# convert string to datetime when making activerecord db query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following table in my DB:

```
class CreateGoogleRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :google_records do |t|
   t.string :user_id
   t.string :date
   t.text :stats
   t.string :account_name
   t.integer :total_conversions
   t.decimal :total_cost

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

I'm looking to create a table inside a view that groups together records by month (I can't use "date created because sometimes they are scraped in bulk from an API).

There is a lot of legacy code involved so rather than convert the column to datetime I was hoping I could convert the date string to a datetime object when performing the query.

I've tried writing a scope like:

```
scope :stats_for_reports, ->(start_date, end_date, user_ids) { select('user_id,  sum(total_cost) as total_cost,  sum(total_conversions) as total_conversions')
                                                              .where('date >= ? and date <= ?', start_date, end_date)
                                                              .where(user_id: user_ids)
                                                              .group(DateTime.parse(:date).month.to_s)}
```

but I receive a `TypeError: can't convert Symbol into String` error.

In the console I've been trying things like:

```
GoogleRecord.where(date: date_start..date_end).group{ |m| DateTime.parse(m.date).month }
```

or

```
GoogleRecord.where(date: date_start..date_end).group(:date).to_date
```

Am I on the right track with any of these?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ActiveRecord before_save, after_save, after_initialize? You may be able to create a DateWrapper (very similar to the EncryptionWrapper below) and convert the string to a date transparent to the rest of the code.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html